# Puppet case statements with integer range

Tags: scripting, puppet, syntax, language

I need to write a case using some ranges in order to write in a better way something like the following spaghetti code :

`if $mem < 1024  { $retvalue = "128M" }
   elsif $mem < 7000  { $retvalue = "160M" }
   elsif $mem < 15000 { $retvalue = "192M" }
   elsif $mem < 31000 { $retvalue = "256M" }
   else { $retvalue = "512M" }`

Is it possible to use a case statements by using the range fuction (on stdlib) or something better than that  ?

BR 
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ranges of this magnitude, I would advise to refrain from creating ranges (i.e., arrays full of integer values for scanning).

Your approach is solid. If you really want a case statement, you could go for a piece of Ruby code and the `inline_template` function, but that has a performance penalty and does not add much in terms of maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet's `case` statement can evaluate expressions and will run the first associated with the first matching case.

It doesn't quite support this:

```
case $mem {
  0..1023:      { $retvalue = "128M" }
  1024..6999:   { $retvalue = "160M" }
  7000...14999: { $retvalue = "192M" }
  15000..30999: { $retvalue = "256M" }
  default:      { $retvalue = "512M" }
}
```

However you can give it expressions and tell it to match the first one that's `true`.

So you *can* do this:

```
case true {
  $mem < 1024:  { $retvalue = "128M" }
  $mem < 7000:  { $retvalue = "160M" }
  $mem < 15000: { $retvalue = "192M" }
  $mem < 31000: { $retvalue = "256M" }
  default:      { $retvalue = "512M" }
}
```

Similarly you could use a [selector](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_conditional.html#selectors) to return the right value:

```
$retvalue = true ? {
  $mem < 1024  => "128M",
  $mem < 7000  => "160M",
  $mem < 15000 => "192M",
  $mem < 31000 => "256M",
  default      => "512M",
}
```